# overflow-y: auto breaking horizontal slider layout in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overflow

I've created a horizontal slider layout on my site at http://www.blueleafstudio.net/portfolio/

Viewed in any browser except IE it works fine, however, in IE 11 (haven't tested in other versions yet) the whole thing is broken as the scrollbars still show up on the nested section elements even though the width is set to 0.

Removal of overflow-y: auto; from the css results in everything working fine in IE except you can't scroll to the bottom of the div to see the rest of the content!

I really don't understand why IE is doing this and all other browsers do something else.  Can anyone suggest a fix, or at the very least an explanation!

Thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved this myself (kind of) by adding and removing and adding `overflow-y: auto` as necessary with jQuery.

I still have absolutely no idea why IE was behaving differently so if anyone has an explanation that would be appreciated...

Death to IE forever.